# Why is the index value zero?

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I don't quote understand the itemInfo = item[0] line in my code. Why is the index value zero? I'm trying to print the title and brand from the product here:

https://api.upcitemdb.com/prod/trial/lookup?upc=012993441012

Here is the code I'm using:'

```
import requests
import json
baseUrl = 'https://api.upcitemdb.com/prod/trial/lookup'

parameters = { 'upc': '012993441012'}

response = requests.get(baseUrl, params = parameters)
print(response.url)
content = response.content
info = json.loads(content)
item = info['items']
itemInfo = item[0]
title = itemInfo['title']
brand = itemInfo['brand']
print(title)
print(brand)
```

Comment: indexing starts at 0 in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this Api, this value only means that items is an Array(Collection) of items, it could return no items, one or more.
Summarizing, zero(0) it's only the first value that comes in, and in programming, most of languages start counting from 0 to n-1.

Comment: Thank you! So if there were more than one title or brand for a product in its dictionary , then to display both I would do item[0:1]?

Comment: No, you should do a for loop then show item[index], which index will show every data inside the item, one by one.

Comment: This code is a version of how you should loop through the values: https://gist.github.com/poentes/1eda03b7fab398a1192e424b1e2cc4ec#file-loop_through_array-py

Answer (score 1):

if you look into the json your getting back, items is a list of dictionaries.
since most programming languages start from 0 for the first item in an array you're basically asking for the first item of that list.

why arrays start from 0 :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering